# Buffer Overflow in C++ while reading virtual memory

Tags: c++, debugging, virtual-memory

I've got a program  which is reading processes virtual memory and some registers for some data, then making amendments to it.

Here I pass the contents of eax register to my function (this seems to work fine, but I thought it might demonstrate what types of data are being involved)

```
    case EXCEPTION_SINGLE_STEP:   // EXCEPTION_SINGLE_STEP = 0x80000004
                    bl_flag = TRUE;
                    memset((void *)&context, 0, 0x2CC);
                    context.ContextFlags = 0x10017;
                    thread = OpenThread(0x1FFFFF, 0, debug_event.dwThreadId);
                    GetThreadContext(thread, &context);
                    context.Eip = context.Eip + 1;

//                  sub_FD4BF0((HANDLE)(*((DWORD *)(lpThreadParameter))), context.Eax);
                    StringToHtml((HANDLE)(dwArray[0]), context.Eax);

                    SetThreadContext(thread, &context);
                    CloseHandle(thread);
                    break;



void StringToHtml(HANDLE hProcess, DWORD address)
{
    WCHAR buff[0x100];
    WCHAR html[0x100];
    DWORD oldProt = 0, real = 0;
    int len = 0;

    VirtualProtectEx(hProcess, (LPVOID)address, 0x200, PAGE_READWRITE, &oldProt);
    ReadProcessMemory(hProcess, (LPCVOID)address, (LPVOID)buff, 0x200, &real);

    len = wcslen(buff);
    int k = 0, j = 0;

    wprintf(L"Found out chat string : \"%s\" \n", buff);

    for (int pp = 0; pp < 0x100; pp++)
        html[pp] = NULL;   
    while(j < len)
    {

        if (buff[j] == L'&')
        {
            if (wcsncmp((const WCHAR *)(buff + j + 1), L"lt;", 3) == 0)
            {
                //html[k] = L'<';
                html[k] = L'<font color="#00FF10">';
                k++;
                j = j + 4;
                continue;
            }
```

I am aware this is an incomplete function snippet. However the issue is arriving at my for loop here.

```
for (int pp = 0; pp < 0x100; pp++)
```

If i enter more than 256 characters (I at first thought this would be enough) then it crashes. I have clearly missed something obvious as I tried doing pp < len which I thought would use the buffer size, however, I still get the same crash.

How can I read the total size of the string entered in the chat into the loop and make it iterate over the WHOLE thing. Or at the very least catch this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you change the size of html and buffer according to the max of your for loop? Maybe that is already the solution.

Comment: Crap. I forgot that. You mean so like:WCHAR buff[len];
    WCHAR html[len];?

Comment: You can not use WCHAR buff[len]; at that point, because len is assigned later on. Just make the buffer large enough, get the length and than adjust the size of html accordingly.

Comment: This has fixed the crash, thanks, i set the buff and html and the loop to 0x1f3d which should easily be enough however it seems to now truncate to 256 characters only? As if it doesn't keep writing past that 0x100 size it had before.

Comment: I sorted it. It was truncating as i had to expand the memory region it was reading in the ReadProcessMemory :D When i stopped to think about why that would happen it was obvious. Thanks for your help pointing out my stupidity :)